# React Native expo: Reading an Image file from android

Tags: android, react-native, expo, expo-file-system

I am using this line to read the image in base64 :

```js
const base64_image = await FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(image, { encoding: 'base64' })
```

The `image` variable is the uri that I have got from the ImagePicker library. This is the code snippet for that:

```js
const pickImage = async () => {
        let permissionResult = await ImagePicker.requestMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync();
        if (permissionResult.granted === false) {
            alert("Permission to access camera roll is required!");
            return;
        } else {
            let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
                mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
                allowsEditing: true,
                aspect: [4, 3],
                quality: 1,
            });
            if (!result.cancelled) {
                setImage(result.uri);
            }
        }
    }
```

setImage is a function from useState that sets the image state. This is working fine and I am getting the uri.

I am facing no problems at all with this method on ios. It is working and I am able to retrieve the image and change it to base 64 string.

The problem is on android, I am always getting the following error:

`[Error: Location 'file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ImagePicker/976e1b20-9fa9-4f80-9e0e-7bee580f0749.jpeg' isn't readable.]`

The location for some reason seems is not readable. What could be problem, given that it is working on ios?

I tried different functions from the expo-file-system library, but the only method to retrieve images from the device is using FileSystem.readAsStringAsync which is not serving the purpose

Answer (score 1):

You can simply enable `base64` and ImagePicker handle it for you.

```js
let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
                mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
                allowsEditing: true,
                aspect: [4, 3],
                quality: 1,
                //image data result will contain base64 data
                base64:true
            });
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked!! I feel silly on how easy it was

Answer (score 0):

You should build an apk version and tested. It is very possible that it is an issue with ExpoGo. It will works fine outside of ExpoGo. Run this on terminal

```
eas build:configure
```

Then change your `eas.json` on project root as follows

```json
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 2.1.0"
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "preview": {
      "distribution": "internal",
      "android": {
        "buildType": "apk"
      }
    },
    "production": {}
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {}
  }
}
```

Then run this on terminal

```
eas build -p android --profile preview
```

[Check eas build guide for detail](https://docs.expo.dev/build/setup/)

Comment: Thank you sir for your answer. I wasn't thinking of building a test app yet but you opened my eyes on it